# unable to setup chroot environment

Tags: ros, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i am trying to install ROS in raspbian using source. I want to setup chroot enviornment. I have followed the steps given at ros installation instruction
But when i run this command
sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static /mnt/usr/bin/

i get and error
cp: cannot create regular file `/mnt/usr/bin/': No such file or directory.

Please help me!..i am not able to understand the steps to be followed so it may be the case that i am stuck for very silly reasons.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64457/unable-to-setup-chroot-environment/) by [Bhargav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5029/bhargav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there, I just stumbled upon your question with some other issue, and am not a pro on this myself, but I would think that you did not mount your Pi's SD card to /mnt using

sudo mount /dev/sdc2 /mnt

or probably some other path, like "/dev/mmcblk0p2" instead of "/dev/sdc2" (which is what I am using). You can find which path it is by calling "sudo fdisk -l" once without the card inserted and once with it. Spot the difference ;)

Then try to copy again.

Also, if you just want to use ROS on the RPi, have a look at my attempt here: http://answers.ros.org/question/63705/problem-using-the-provided-groovy-rpi-image/#64027
(darn, I'm still not allowed to post links...)

---

Originally posted by [jmueller](https://answers.ros.org/users/5000/jmueller/) with karma: 50 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bhargav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5029/bhargav/) on 2013-06-12**:
Thank you!...yes i did the same and it is fixed now.